# Bootstrap 3 how to make columns in a row horizontally centered

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So here's the issue with it, I'm trying to make columns horizontally centered in rows, so here's the fiddle: `jsfiddle.net/y73f1bp0/`

There you will see a few rows, and each row has 4 columns at most.
On large, medium screen - 4 columns
On Small screen         - 2 columns
On Extra Small screen   - 1 column

So if you resize it everything works fine, but here I have a case, scroll down to the very bottom to see the last row, it contains 3 columns, so I just want to show a case that there can be such circumstances where just one row can have, one, two, three or fours columns.

Problem.
The problem is that when I have less than 4 columns in a row, they are not placed in the center of the row, but they are going from left to right, which is not what I want, I need them to be placed exactly at the center of the row, no matter if its just one, two or three columns.

I tried using display: flex; stuff with align-items and justify-content properties, and it looks like it gets the job done, but then I get weird side effect when resizing these columns don't line up properly and column heights are not quite the same, so I guess the 'flex' thing works quite differently than regular divs, and should not be used in conjuction with bootstrap 3 responsive classes. You can take a look at the side effect when resizing here: http://jsfiddle.net/ub35xgrk/ I just applied display: flex and content alignment to the center, for each row.

Requirements.
The requirements are that I cannot use anything above Bootstrap 3, but of course I can use some additional CSS classes that could help me, since I'm changing a few years old WordPress theme, which gets the job done quite nicely for me, but I need to tweak some parts, so I can't just simply switch to some other CSS framework or Bootstrap version that easily.

Any help would be really appreciated of what else I could try, when using flex it works really nice, the way I want it, but the side effect which breaks the columns when resizing is of course the deal breaker for me.

Additional stuff:
Also I can't use bootstrap 3 offset classes, since they only work best for even number of columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing your second fiddle needed for the row was `flex-wrap: wrap` to tell the browser it’s okay to wrap columns to the next row so it doesn’t try to squeeze the columns into the same row. The `justify-content: center` that you had would do the centering of the content in the row.

You had five rows of similar content in your original layout. If you don’t need the content separated, you could put everything into one `row` and let flex handle the layout – I included a second version in my snippet.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<style>
   .row {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: center;
   }

   .product_heading {
      min-height: 99px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
   }

   .product_cat_col {
      padding-left: 2%;
      padding-right: 2%;
      padding-top: 40px;
      padding-bottom: 40px;
      text-align: center;
   }

   .product_cat_img {
      width: 34.5rem;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
   }

   @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .product_cat_img {
            width: auto;
      }
   }
</style>

<h2 style="margin: 10rem 0 5rem">Original configuration &ndash; with three rows</h2>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 product_cat_col">
            <div><label class="label label-danger">Udsolgt</label></div>
            <hr>
            <img class="product_cat_img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61UbWeyxudL._SL1113_.jpg">
            <hr>
            <div class="text-center product_heading">
               <h3 class="lora-font" style="font-size: 1.5em;">Nat snack</h3>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <div class="product-price price "><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>169,00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">DKK</span></bdi></span></div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <a class="shop-button bg-white" href="https://asun.dk/urteblandinger/asun-nat-snack/">LÆS MERE</a>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 product_cat_col">
            <div>&nbsp;</div>
            <hr>
            <img class="product_cat_img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61UbWeyxudL._SL1113_.jpg">
            <hr>
            <div class="text-center product_heading">
               <h3 class="lora-font" style="font-size: 1.5em;">Kropsrensning</h3>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <div class="product-price price "><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>169,00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">DKK</span></bdi></span></div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <a class="shop-button bg-white" href="https://asun.dk/urteblandinger/asun-kropsrensning/">LÆS MERE</a>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 product_cat_col">
            <div><label class="label label-danger">Udsolgt</label></div>
            <hr>
            <img class="product_cat_img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61UbWeyxudL._SL1113_.jpg">
            <hr>
            <div class="text-center product_heading">
               <h3 class="lora-font" style="font-size: 1.5em;">Stærk Immunitet</h3>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <div class="product-price price "><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>169,00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">DKK</span></bdi></span></div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <a class="shop-button bg-white" href="https://asun.dk/urteblandinger/asun-staerk-immunitet/">LÆS MERE</a>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 product_cat_col">
            <div><label class="label label-danger">Udsolgt</label></div>
            <hr>
            <img class="product_cat_img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61UbWeyxudL._SL1113_.jpg">
            <hr>
            <div class="text-center product_heading">
               <h3 class="lora-font" style="font-size: 1.5em;">fiberblanding Med tranebær</h3>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <div class="product-price price "><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>189,00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">DKK</span></bdi></span></div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <a class="shop-button bg-white" href="https://asun.dk/blandinger-af-kostfibre/asun-fiberblanding-med-tranebaer/">LÆS MERE</a>
            </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 product_cat_col">
            <div><label class="label label-danger">Udsolgt</label></div>
            <hr>
            <img class="product_cat_img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61UbWeyxudL._SL1113_.jpg">
            <hr>
            <div class="text-center product_heading">
               <h3 class="lora-font" style="font-size: 1.5em;">inhalator vitamin B12</h3>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <div class="product-price price "><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>89,00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">DKK</span></bdi></span></div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <a class="shop-button bg-white" href="https://asun.dk/inhalatorer/asun-inhalator-vitamin-b12/">LÆS MERE</a>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 product_cat_col">
            <div><label class="label label-danger">Udsolgt</label></div>
            <hr>
            <img class="product_cat_img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61UbWeyxudL._SL1113_.jpg">
            <hr>
            <div class="text-center product_heading">
               <h3 class="lora-font" style="font-size: 1.5em;">inhalator Vitamin B12 (jordbær)</h3>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <div class="product-price price "><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>89,00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">DKK</span></bdi></span></div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <a class="shop-button bg-white" href="https://asun.dk/inhalatorer/asun-inhalator-vitamin-b12-jordbaer/">LÆS MERE</a>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 product_cat_col">
            <div><label class="label label-danger">Udsolgt</label></div>
            <hr>
            <img class="product_cat_img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61UbWeyxudL._SL1113_.jpg">
            <hr>
            <div class="text-center product_heading">
               <h3 class="lora-font" style="font-size: 1.5em;">transdermal vitaminplaster Vitamin B12</h3>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <div class="product-price price "><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>189,00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">DKK</span></bdi></span></div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <a class="shop-button bg-white" href="https://asun.dk/vitamin-plastre/asun-transdermal-vitaminplaster-vitamin-b12/">LÆS MERE</a>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 product_cat_col">
            <div><label class="label label-danger">Udsolgt</label></div>
            <hr>
            <img class="product_cat_img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61UbWeyxudL._SL1113_.jpg">
            <hr>
            <div class="text-center product_heading">
               <h3 class="lora-font" style="font-size: 1.5em;">transdermal vitaminplaster Vitamin D3</h3>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <div class="product-price price "><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>189,00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">DKK</span></bdi></span></div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <a class="shop-button bg-white" href="https://asun.dk/vitamin-plastre/asun-transdermal-vitaminplaster-vitamin-d3/">LÆS MERE</a>
            </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 product_cat_col">
            <div><label class="label label-danger">Udsolgt</label></div>
            <hr>
            <img class="product_cat_img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61UbWeyxudL._SL1113_.jpg">
            <hr>
            <div class="text-center product_heading">
               <h3 class="lora-font" style="font-size: 1.5em;">vingummi vitaminer Til øjne</h3>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <div class="product-price price "><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>129,00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">DKK</span></bdi></span></div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <a class="shop-button bg-white" href="https://asun.dk/vitaminer-vingummier/asun-vingummi-vitaminer-til-oejne/">LÆS MERE</a>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 product_cat_col">
            <div><label class="label label-danger">Udsolgt</label></div>
            <hr>
            <img class="product_cat_img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61UbWeyxudL._SL1113_.jpg">
            <hr>
            <div class="text-center product_heading">
               <h3 class="lora-font" style="font-size: 1.5em;">Vingummi vitaminer Hår, negle, hud</h3>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <div class="product-price price "><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>149,00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">DKK</span></bdi></span></div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <a class="shop-button bg-white" href="https://asun.dk/vitaminer-vingummier/asun-vingummi-vitaminer-haar-negle-hud/">LÆS MERE</a>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 product_cat_col">
            <div><label class="label label-danger">Udsolgt</label></div>
            <hr>
            <img class="product_cat_img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61UbWeyxudL._SL1113_.jpg">
            <hr>
            <div class="text-center product_heading">
               <h3 class="lora-font" style="font-size: 1.5em;">vingummibamser Omega-3 og multivitaminer</h3>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <div class="product-price price "><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>99,00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">DKK</span></bdi></span></div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <a class="shop-button bg-white" href="https://asun.dk/vitaminer-vingummier/asun-vingummibamser-omega-3-og-multivitaminer/">LÆS MERE</a>
            </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<h2 style="margin: 10rem 0 5rem">Alternate method using all columns in one row</h2>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 product_cat_col">
            <div><label class="label label-danger">Udsolgt</label></div>
            <hr>
            <img class="product_cat_img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61UbWeyxudL._SL1113_.jpg">
            <hr>
            <div class="text-center product_heading">
               <h3 class="lora-font" style="font-size: 1.5em;">Nat snack</h3>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <div class="product-price price "><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>169,00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">DKK</span></bdi></span></div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <a class="shop-button bg-white" href="https://asun.dk/urteblandinger/asun-nat-snack/">LÆS MERE</a>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 product_cat_col">
            <div>&nbsp;</div>
            <hr>
            <img class="product_cat_img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61UbWeyxudL._SL1113_.jpg">
            <hr>
            <div class="text-center product_heading">
               <h3 class="lora-font" style="font-size: 1.5em;">Kropsrensning</h3>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <div class="product-price price "><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>169,00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">DKK</span></bdi></span></div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <a class="shop-button bg-white" href="https://asun.dk/urteblandinger/asun-kropsrensning/">LÆS MERE</a>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 product_cat_col">
            <div><label class="label label-danger">Udsolgt</label></div>
            <hr>
            <img class="product_cat_img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61UbWeyxudL._SL1113_.jpg">
            <hr>
            <div class="text-center product_heading">
               <h3 class="lora-font" style="font-size: 1.5em;">Stærk Immunitet</h3>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <div class="product-price price "><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>169,00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">DKK</span></bdi></span></div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <a class="shop-button bg-white" href="https://asun.dk/urteblandinger/asun-staerk-immunitet/">LÆS MERE</a>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 product_cat_col">
            <div><label class="label label-danger">Udsolgt</label></div>
            <hr>
            <img class="product_cat_img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61UbWeyxudL._SL1113_.jpg">
            <hr>
            <div class="text-center product_heading">
               <h3 class="lora-font" style="font-size: 1.5em;">fiberblanding Med tranebær</h3>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <div class="product-price price "><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>189,00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">DKK</span></bdi></span></div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <a class="shop-button bg-white" href="https://asun.dk/blandinger-af-kostfibre/asun-fiberblanding-med-tranebaer/">LÆS MERE</a>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 product_cat_col">
            <div><label class="label label-danger">Udsolgt</label></div>
            <hr>
            <img class="product_cat_img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61UbWeyxudL._SL1113_.jpg">
            <hr>
            <div class="text-center product_heading">
               <h3 class="lora-font" style="font-size: 1.5em;">fiberblanding Med sorbitol</h3>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <div class="product-price price "><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>189,00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">DKK</span></bdi></span></div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <a class="shop-button bg-white" href="https://asun.dk/blandinger-af-kostfibre/asun-fiberblanding-med-sorbitol/">LÆS MERE</a>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 product_cat_col">
            <div><label class="label label-danger">Udsolgt</label></div>
            <hr>
            <img class="product_cat_img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61UbWeyxudL._SL1113_.jpg">
            <hr>
            <div class="text-center product_heading">
               <h3 class="lora-font" style="font-size: 1.5em;">fiberblanding Original</h3>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <div class="product-price price "><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>189,00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">DKK</span></bdi></span></div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <a class="shop-button bg-white" href="https://asun.dk/blandinger-af-kostfibre/asun-fiberblanding-original/">LÆS MERE</a>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 product_cat_col">
            <div><label class="label label-danger">Udsolgt</label></div>
            <hr>
            <img class="product_cat_img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61UbWeyxudL._SL1113_.jpg">
            <hr>
            <div class="text-center product_heading">
               <h3 class="lora-font" style="font-size: 1.5em;">inhalator Diet</h3>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <div class="product-price price "><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>89,00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">DKK</span></bdi></span></div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <a class="shop-button bg-white" href="https://asun.dk/inhalatorer/asun-inhalator-diet/">LÆS MERE</a>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 product_cat_col">
            <div><label class="label label-danger">Udsolgt</label></div>
            <hr>
            <img class="product_cat_img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61UbWeyxudL._SL1113_.jpg">
            <hr>
            <div class="text-center product_heading">
               <h3 class="lora-font" style="font-size: 1.5em;">inhalator Energy + B12</h3>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <div class="product-price price "><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>109,00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">DKK</span></bdi></span></div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <a class="shop-button bg-white" href="https://asun.dk/inhalatorer/asun-inhalator-energy-b12/">LÆS MERE</a>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 product_cat_col">
            <div><label class="label label-danger">Udsolgt</label></div>
            <hr>
            <img class="product_cat_img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61UbWeyxudL._SL1113_.jpg">
            <hr>
            <div class="text-center product_heading">
               <h3 class="lora-font" style="font-size: 1.5em;">inhalator Relax</h3>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <div class="product-price price "><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>89,00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">DKK</span></bdi></span></div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <a class="shop-button bg-white" href="https://asun.dk/inhalatorer/asun-inhalator-relax/">LÆS MERE</a>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 product_cat_col">
            <div><label class="label label-danger">Udsolgt</label></div>
            <hr>
            <img class="product_cat_img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61UbWeyxudL._SL1113_.jpg">
            <hr>
            <div class="text-center product_heading">
               <h3 class="lora-font" style="font-size: 1.5em;">Vingummi vitaminer Hår, negle, hud</h3>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <div class="product-price price "><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>149,00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">DKK</span></bdi></span></div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <a class="shop-button bg-white" href="https://asun.dk/vitaminer-vingummier/asun-vingummi-vitaminer-haar-negle-hud/">LÆS MERE</a>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 product_cat_col">
            <div><label class="label label-danger">Udsolgt</label></div>
            <hr>
            <img class="product_cat_img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61UbWeyxudL._SL1113_.jpg">
            <hr>
            <div class="text-center product_heading">
               <h3 class="lora-font" style="font-size: 1.5em;">vingummibamser Omega-3 og multivitaminer</h3>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <div class="product-price price "><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>99,00&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">DKK</span></bdi></span></div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
               <a class="shop-button bg-white" href="https://asun.dk/vitaminer-vingummier/asun-vingummibamser-omega-3-og-multivitaminer/">LÆS MERE</a>
            </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I don’t know for sure why you question got a couple of down-votes, but it may be because you put your example in a fiddle and then linked to it, rather than using the snippet tool. The snippet tool does make it easier to understand your question without having to visit another site.

*I deleted some of your rows so they two examples would fit within the snippet character limit.*

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort :) This really solves my issue. Yeah the problem with my question was that I probably didn't provide good enough example here in code which would be reproducible easily, I thought the code is gonna be long since I don't really know what affected my layout not working properly, I couldn't identify the most necessary parts that quick.